# Folders.hasNext() returning false from Google Sheets but true when called directly from Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

**Overview**

Im making a script for my google sheet.

I have a helper method which takes email for parameter (string) and then invites that email to google drives  folder.

I also have edit() function which gets called whenever a field in Google Sheets is changed.

---

**Problem:**

When helper method is called by itself from Google Scripts it works fine and I get an invite. 
When helper method is triggered from edit() while im in google sheets, it doesn't go all the way through to send an invitation. It stops at while function which returns false:

```
 var newFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("New Folder");
  Logger.log(newFolder.hasNext());
  while(newFolder.hasNext()) {      -> returns false while in google sheets
    var folder = newFolder.next();
    Logger.log("folder -> " + folder);  
    folder.addViewer(newPersonEmail);
  }
```

---

**What I tried:**

`Logger.log` shows that `newFolder.hasNext()` returns false while script
   gets called from `edit()` function (when im making a change in google
   sheets).  But it returns true when I simply debug function in Google
   scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register `edit()` for the specific user. It's not possible for the simple `onEdit` trigger.

It returns false because there is nothing for the current user. And it's true.

===== Updated =====

As for me, I think It's normal to create a triggers for users every time when we needs their scopes. Suppose we need to force a user to register a trigger. He has to run `regTrigger()`

```
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} e
 */
function edit(e) {
  // there is the edit eveng action
}

/**
 * Register trigger
 * @returns {GoogleAppsScript.Script.Trigger}
 */
function regTrigger() {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(activeSpreadsheet).filter(function(
    trigger
  ) {
    return (
      trigger.getEventType() === ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT &&
      trigger.getHandlerFunction() === 'edit'
    );
  });

  if (triggers.length) return triggers[0];

  return ScriptApp.newTrigger('edit')
    .forSpreadsheet(activeSpreadsheet)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}
```

Now your task is to give the user the opportunity to perform this function once (`regTrigger`). For example, from the menu. Or make it happen when you open the Table forcing some events.

Comment: I see. 

Can you please give me bit more guidance, im not experienced with google scripts. How do i register it to specific user?

Comment: @TheGarrus please check the last update of my message. Thanks.

Comment: How can i pass email and shouldSend boolean to onTrigger function? 
I made it run onEdit but it also needs to have these params.